# CPU scheduling policy using FCFS

Tags: algorithm, cpu, cpu-usage

What is the formula to find average waiting time for CPU scheduling Policy using FCFS given Arrival Time,CPU time needed and process priority.
I already have wasted a lot time googling and finding irrelevant results

Answer (score 1):

1. Solve this problem for a single priority [Kingman formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingman%27s_formula) should help)
2. Assuming no lower priority job can get CPU when a higher priority job needs it come up with some theory about jobs distribution by priorities
3. Using result of #2 calculate weighted waiting times across all priorities